# Reopened tabs include several that were separately closed earlier. How to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, chromium, ubuntu-13.10

I have been experiencing an issue with the chromium browser where tabs that I close *separately* before closing chromium as a whole are reopened with the tabs that I left open when I start chromium again. This behavior is experienced even if all extensions are disabled.

To show what I mean, here is an example of a common scenario:

1. I have my email, some article, a javadoc page, stack overflow, and a settings panel open in separate tabs on the same window, and with no other windows open.
2. I click the <kbd>x</kbd> button on the tabs for the article, javadoc page, and settings panel, in that order, closing those tabs.
3. I open another stackoverflow question in a new tab.
4. I click on the window <kbd>x</kbd> button, closing the entire window.
5. Some time later (including after restarting), I click on the chromium icon in the sidebar, opening the web browser.
6. The newly-opened window has as tabs: my email, the article I had closed, the javadoc page I had closed, stack overflow, and the stackoverflow question I opened right before closing the browser. (The settings page, however, remains closed, same with any other `chrome://` page.)

This is a problem. I do not want those pages to reopen, especially since in other cases it might instead be a dozen tabs with youtube videos or flash applications, all competing for processing power and bandwidth, and freezing the browser when I open it.

How can I fix this problem?

---

Version info (from the `chrome://version` page):

> Chromium:    31.0.1650.63 (Developer Build 31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20131204.1) Ubuntu 13.10
>   OS:  Linux
>   Blink:   537.36 (@163124)
>   JavaScript:  V8 3.21.18.13
>   Flash:   11.2 r202
>   User Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/31.0.1650.63 Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
>   Command Line:     /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --flag-switches-begin --enable-fast-unload --enable-nacl --flag-switches-end
>   Executable Path: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser

Comment: For some reason, there is no Ubuntu-13.10 tag on superuser yet. Could someone with more rep please retag?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Chrome behaves the same way on Linux as it does on Windows, in your setting have you tried to switch "On Startup" category to "Open New Tab Page"

Comment: Yes, I tried it and that setting functions as it should. However, this is not the same thing. I want only the tabs I left open to reopen, while currently it also reopens several closed tabs alongside them.

Comment: What setting do you have currently selected: "Continue where I left off"

Comment: Yes, that is my setting.

Comment: Have you tried different version? Possible bug with the history of open pages.

Comment: no I have not. I will try that if no better options appear.